# Is it more efficient to keep DOM elements on the page or to re-render them as needed?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a dialog box that has settings associated with it. When the user clicks the "settings" button, a form is displayed so they can modify them.

**What is more efficient**:

- to have the settings div exist hidden on the page and display when needed

OR

- to create the settings div and populate it with data when needed?

In the first scenario you don't need to create the DOM elements and populate them every time, but if there are many dialog boxes open at once (a common situation) then the amount of elements on the page is pretty large and many of them are not going to be used often. But in the second situation, elements are created and appended to the DOM which gets expensive.

Comment: How many different settings dialog boxes are there on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to "cache" your html on the page, but enforce browser to do not render it until necessary (until user request the data, or simply scroll to it). The main idea is to add your html (with data) to the page, but comment it out. For example,

```
<div id="cached-html">
  <!--
    <div>
    ...some custom html here
    </div>
  -->
</div>
```

Then once user requested the html, you can do the following:

```
var html = document.getElementById('cached-html'),
            inner = html.innerHTML;
html.innerHTML = inner.substring(4, inner.length - 4);
```

Pros. is that you don't bother your browser with **initial** rendering (later you can simply user `display:none` to hide it again), so your page renders faster.

And another note - if your data (and as a consequence inner html) changes frequently, then it will be better to re-render it each time user request it, but if it is almost static, then hide/show should be more effective.

Answer (score 1):

There can be problems either way, it depends on your page. If you already have a lot of elements on the page, it may be better load add them when you need them. If your page is already very "scripty" you may want to load the elements and show them when needed.

The real question is what would be better for your page, more script, or more dom elements.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to display same setting div at multiple places.
Keeping that hidden is a better solution.

Remember that creating a new dom element or cloning a existing dom element gives almost same performance, but for code clarity/maintainence cloning or template is better.

**Implementation using template**: Make a template of div setting and keep that hidden:

```
<div class="template_setting">
Your settings(children of template_setting)
</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery code:

-Whenever someone opens a dialogue box, make a clone of childrens of template_setting and append to div_dialogue.

-As you may have multiple templates on the same page( which is not always true).
Apply a custom event on the id of newly created setting div.( keep id of each setting div different, you can increment each one by some character/number).

```
$('#dialogue_opener').click(function(event){
 $('.template_setting').children().clone().appendTo(div_dialogue)
 .trigger('adjustSettingID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a hybrid solution. Load the "settings" div after the page is ready. This way, the user won't feel the extra "expense", *and* you'll have the div ready for when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I've typically seen that rendering from JavaScript is pretty darn fast. I've built lots of "just in time" menus, grids, and forms and the users can't tell the difference. The nice thing about it is that you don't have to keep a form current, just blow it away and default everything to the data in you settings object. Makes for cleaner code in my opinion.